# Cannot use SSL certificate when using Git on openSUSE

Tags: git, https, opensuse

I'm using Git on openSUSE and receive the following error when trying to clone a Git repository via HTTPS.

```
$ git clone https://example.com/foo.git
Cloning into 'foo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://example.com/foo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How do I fix this? I'm an openSUSE novice but am knowledgeable of other Linux distros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Root CA certificates are likely not installed on the system.

Install the certificates from the command line:

`$ zypper install ca-certificates{,-cacert,-mozilla}`